# after_compile hook not getting called for "cordova run"

Tags: cordova, hook, cordova-cli, cordova-4

"cordova --help" states that "run ... Run project (including prepare && compile)". What I understand is that calling "cordova run android" calls prepare and compile processes. It indeed calls.

However, it only calls the "prepare" related hooks (before_prepare and after_prepare) and doesn't call compile related hooks (before_compile & after_compile). IF I call "cordova compile" specifically, the hooks are getting called and executed correctly. Any help?

I am using cordova 4.2.0. My hooks are written in node.js and reside in "/hooks" directory.

Comment: Can anyone help please? It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found out that this is a bug as reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8287)